# django ajax POST 404 not found

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

Recently I learned ajax but now i am trying to implement in my fjango project but it is not working.
**signup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('submit', '#signup', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
        var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
        var password1 = $('input[name="password1"]').val();
        var password2 = $('input[name="password2"]').val();


    var url = '/signup'
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
       req.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                if(req.responseText == 'true' ){
                    alert('account created')
                }
          }
       };
       req.open("POST", url, true);
       req.send();
    })
});
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',login_required(StockView.as_view(), login_url='login'), name='stock'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('signup/', SignupView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('logout',LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('addproduct/', login_required(AddProduct.as_view(), login_url='login'), name='addproduct'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', login_required(EditProduct.as_view(), login_url='login'), name='editproduct'),
    path('delete/', login_required(DeleteProducts.as_view(), login_url='login'), name='deleteproducts'),
```

**view.py**

```
class SignupView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'stock/signup.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm()
        args = {'form': form}

        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

**form.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','name':'name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),help_text='Password Should Match',label='Password')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),label='Password Confirmation')

    class Meta:
        model = AppUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2' )
```

**template.html**

```
  <form method="post" id="signup" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Signup</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="{% static 'assets/signup.js' %}"></script>
```

**CONSOLE ERROR**:
signup.js:21 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @   signup.js:21
dispatch    @   jquery-2.1.4.js:4435
elemData.handle @   jquery-2.1.4.js:4121

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash here `path('signup/', SignupView.as_view(), name='signup')` and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Try to send csrf token as you're trying to send data using the POST method. Inspect the form and you get a hidden input tag of csrf_token, include that in you ajax.

Comment: how I can do this in csrf in ajax ?

Comment: inspect the form, you'll find below the form tag an input tag of the hidden attribute, grab that input tag value using javascript or jquery whatever you like and send it in your "data" in ajax

Comment: because you're csrf_token is not valid or it's not getting to the server correctly